# date_diff retorna diferença incorreta

Tags: php, javascript, data, localhost, diff

Estava fazendo uns testes com esta função, mas ela retorna uma diferença incorreta, como faço para contornar isso?

Exemplo: quando comparado a diferença entre dia 01/01 com 01/03 retornar a diferença de um mês, e só quando é dia 04/03 que retornar os dois meses.

**Correto:**

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-01-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-03-04');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
echo $interval->format('%R%m month');
```

**Resultado:**

> +62 days+2 month

---

**Incorreto:**

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-01-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-03-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
echo $interval->format('%R%m month');
```

**Resultado:**

> +59 days+1 month

Comment: *The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".* – [Do manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método DateInterval::format() não recalcula pontos de transporte em sequências de tempo nem em segmentos de data. Isso é esperado porque não é possível estourar valores como "32 dias", o que poderia ser interpretado como algo de "1 mês e 4 dias" a "1 mês e 1 dia".
[Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)